# issue with routing & action in controller - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> i get the below error related to the links accept & decline in my
>   views - it's a routing issue but i am unsure how to go about it. could
>   one kindly advise me on how to correct this

error message

```
No route matches {:action=>"accept", :controller=>"friendships", :id=>"emma"}

No route matches {:action=>"decline", :controller=>"friendships", :id=>"emma"}
```

> views/users/_friends.html.erb

```
<% @user.requested_friends.each do |requester| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to(image_tag("img-profile-image-default.png"), requester) %></td> 
    <td><%= link_to requester.firstname, requester %></td>
    <td>
      <%= link_to "Accept",
                  { controller: "friendships", 
                    action: "accept",
                    id: requester.firstname } %>
      <%= link_to "Decline",
                  { controller: "friendships", 
                    action: "decline",
                    id: requester.firstname },
                    confirm: "Really decline friendship with #{requester.firstname}?" %>
    </td> 
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

> friendships_controller.rb

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :setup_friends

  def create
    Friendship.request(@user, @friend)
    flash[:notice] = "Friend request sent."
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def accept
    if @user.requested_friends.include?(@friend)
      Friendship.accept(@user, @friend)
      flash[:notice] = "Friendship with #{@friend.firstname} accepted!"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "No friendship request from #{@friend.firstname}."
    end
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def decline
    if @user.requested_friends.include?(@friend)
      Friendship.breakup(@user, @friend)
      flash[:notice] = "Friendship with #{@friend.firstname} declined"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "No friendship request from #{@friend.firstname}."
    end
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def delete
    if @user.friends.include?(@friend)
      Friendship.breakup(@user, @friend)
      flash[:notice] = "Friendship with #{@friend.firstname} deleted!"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "You aren't friends with #{@friend.firstname}"
    end
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private
  def setup_friends
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @friend = User.find_by_email(params[:id])
  end
end
```

> routes file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :friendships, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
end


             friendships POST   /friendships(.:format)         friendships#create
              friendship PATCH  /friendships/:id(.:format)     friendships#update
                         PUT    /friendships/:id(.:format)     friendships#update
                         DELETE /friendships/:id(.:format)     friendships#destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have any routes for accept or decline. Only Create, Update, Destroy as I see. You are doing it in friendships controller so in my opinion it is better to send friendship id as main param.
You can do it like this

```
resources :friendships, only: [:create, :update, :destroy] do
 member do
  post :accept
  post :decline
 end
end
```

This will create you routes and path helpers like

```
accept_friendship_path(id: friendship.id)
decline_friendship_path(id: friendship.id)
```

Or you can use

```
accept_friendship_path(friendship)
```

You can still send friend id as param adding it to link doing it like this

```
link_to "Accept", accept_friendship_path(friendship, friend_id: requester.id)
```